# Caminho json para pegar valor de api

Tags: json, api

Como pegar o valor do **low** da seguinte `api`:

```js
[{"idreg":"257052","code":"USD","codein":"BRL","name":"D\u00f3lar Comercial",      
  "high":"3.4026","pctChange":"1.143","open":"0","bid":"3.3703","ask":"3.3713",  
  "timestamp":"1481828340000","low":"3.367","notFresh":"0","varBid":"0.0381",   
  "create_date":"2016-12-15 17:30:02"}]
```

Não entendo muito bem quais são as regras de caminho `json` mas tentei da seguinte forma:

```php
<?php    
    $json_file = file_get_contents("https://economia.awesomeapi.com.br/json/USD-BRL/1");   
    $dados = json_decode($json_file);    
    echo $dados->low;
?>
```

***O que estou fazendo errado?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$json_file = file_get_contents("https://economia.awesomeapi.com.br/json/USD-BRL/1");   
$dados = json_decode($json_file);

echo $dados[0]->low;


?>
```

Comment: por que tem que ser adicionado este "[0]"

Comment: É o índice.

Pense que o json que retornou poderia ter varias linhas, o numero entre [] significa qual é. Nesse seu caso foi apenas uma, portanto é "0"

Answer (score 2):

Podes fazer assim:

```
$json_file = file_get_contents("https://economia.awesomeapi.com.br/json/USD-BRL/1");
$dados = json_decode($json_file);
echo $dados[0]->low; // 3.367
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](http://ideone.com/HpumG1)

Podes ir buscar os dados como array também:

```
...
$dados = json_decode($json_file, true);
echo $dados[0]['low']; // 3.367
```

Nota que no formato dos dados:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [idreg] => 257052
            [code] => USD
            [codein] => BRL
            [name] => Dólar Comercial
            [high] => 3.4026
            [pctChange] => 1.143
            [open] => 0
            [bid] => 3.3703
            [ask] => 3.3713
            [timestamp] => 1481828340000
            [low] => 3.367
            [notFresh] => 0
            [varBid] => 0.0381
            [create_date] => 2016-12-15 17:30:02
        )

)
```

Estes estão todos na chave 0 do nosso array principal, sendo que estes também por sua vez são um array associativo se `json_decode($json_file, true)` senão são um objeto por default `json_decode($json_file)`, e deves aceder `$dados[0]->PROPRIEDADE_QUE_QUERES`

Comment: ótima explicação :D, vlw

Comment: (: hehe obagdo @picossi